# Omit empty function signiture on listener creation

Tags: java, inner-classes

Sorry for the newbie question - Is it possible to omit the empty function signatures when implementing the MouseListener class (or every other inner class)?

 So the code will shrink by few lines?

```
    JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
    btnExit.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}
        @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {System.exit(0);}
        @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}
        @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}
        @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {}
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [`MouseAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) and only override the function which is required

```
btnExit.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {System.exit(0);}

});
```

Comment: Damn it !! I wanted to tell him that !